# Is it possible to view the exact site addresses a program is accessing on a Mac?

Tags: wireless-networking, command-line, connection

This might be possible on Windows or Linux, if so I'll try to change my OS, but I'd like to know if it's possible to see websites a program is looking at or trying to connect to. I need this for debug services on a script I'm trying to run for my router.

Comment: I know product recommendations are frowned on as answers.. so just as a comment - [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) is designed to do exactly this, as a user controlled outbound firewall, preventing unwanted 'phoning home' from apps. It also has a current connections drop menu & per-app port/ip/host/domain rules for filtering

Answer (score 2):

You can use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

For wireshark [filtering by process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339691/filter-by-process-pid-in-wireshark) discussed here

Or from terminal you can use tcpdump command